# How to create a variable in R and access it in the RStudio terminal

Tags: r, bash, shell, terminal, rstudio

Is it possible to create a variable in the RStudio console, for example:

```
x <- 3
```

and then access that variable in RStudio's terminal?

```
echo $x
3
```